# select Entity using Linq to xml

Tags: linq-to-xml

i'm new to linq , iv'e got an xml file as such

```
  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
   <NewDataSet>
      <Order>
          <OrderID>1</OrderID>
          <ProductID>11</ProductID>
          <UnitPrice>14.0000</UnitPrice>
          <Quantity>12</Quantity>
          <Discount>0</Discount>
      </Order>
      <Order>
          <OrderID>2</OrderID>
          <ProductID>42</ProductID>
          <UnitPrice>9.8000</UnitPrice>
          <Quantity>10</Quantity>
          <Discount>0</Discount>
      </Order>
      .
      .
 </NewDataSet>
```

now i'm trying to query all the elements named "Order"

```
        var query = from e in XElement.Load("..//..//OrderDetailsData.xml").Elements("Order")
                    select e.Element("Order");
```

this returns nothing

iv'e also tried

```
        var query = from e in XElement.Load("..//..//OrderDetailsData.xml").Descendants("NewDataSet").Elements("Order")
        select e.Element("Order");
```

the question is how do i select multiple elements named Order ?
(not that this selects even a single element)
is there spouse to be some kind of lambada "where e => e " or something of the sort ...

to conclude .. i just don't understand how to query using linq to xml as i would linq a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply want `var query = XElement.Load("..//..//OrderDetailsData.xml").Elements("Order");` or if you really think that a `from select` is helpful then use `var query = from order in XElement.Load("..//..//OrderDetailsData.xml").Elements("Order") select order;`.

Comment: thanks , i forgot to comment on this by i figured it out eventually .